# Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ a sequence of independent random variables distributed $bin(n,\frac{\lambda}{n})$ , where $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$.

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n}$ a sequence of independent random variables distributed $bin(n,\frac{\lambda}{n})$ , where $\lambda \in (0,\infty)$

Prove that the sequence converges in distribution to a
Poisson variable. Prove also that if we have a $Zn$, where $Zn =\frac{X_{n}}{n}$
, the sequence converges on
distribution to a degenerate variable but asymptotically to a Poisson.

The first part is easy to prove, I used characteristic functions and I arrived to a Poisson characteristic function.

I don´t know how to prove $Z_{n}$ convergence.

Comment: It seems that $X_k$ is not defined for any $k>n$ and so convergence does not make sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using moments of Binomial distribution check that $EZ_n^{2} \to 0$. This implies that $Z_n \to 0$ in probability, hence also in distribution.

Comment: Thank you!! ...